# SpringRoo 2.0.RC1 - How can i use date Calenderfields in entityFormatExpression and got correct format

Tags: spring-roo

**date Calendar**

When i use date Calender field in entityFormatExpression i got a

```
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Pet --sequenceName PET_SEQ --entityFormatExpression "#{name} (#{type}) birthDay: #{birthDay}"
field date --fieldName birthDay --type java.util.Calendar --notNull --dateTimeFormatPattern "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

Log Warning

```
2017-03-22 10:43:55.738  WARN - QP: - 6424 --- [io-8082-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionRes
olver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableExcep
tion: Could not write content: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.roo.petclinic.domain
.Pet] to type [java.lang.String] for value 'Pet {id='1', version='0', sendReminders='false', name='M
imi', weight='4.5', birthDay='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1490137200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAl
lFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSa
vings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,of
fset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,st
artDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTi
me=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF
_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0
,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]', ITERABLE_T
O_ADD_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!', ITERABLE_TO_REMOVE_C
ANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!'}org.springframework.roo.petc
linic.domain.Pet@1f'; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationExceptio
n: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from @javax.validation.constraints.NotNu
ll @javax.persistence.Temporal @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Grego
rianCalendar to java.lang.String (through reference chain: io.springlets.data.web.select2.Select2Dat
aWithConversion["results"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.roo.petclinic.domain.Pet] to type [java.lang.Stri
ng] for value 'Pet {id='1', version='0', sendReminders='false', name='Mimi', weight='4.5', birthDay=
'java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1490137200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,
zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=tru
e,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=36000
00,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600
000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],fi
rstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_
OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=
0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]', ITERABLE_TO_ADD_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='T
he given Iterable of items to add can't be null!', ITERABLE_TO_REMOVE_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The give
n Iterable of items to add can't be null!'}org.springframework.roo.petclinic.domain.Pet@1f'; nested
exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conv
ersion problem, cannot convert from @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Tempora
l @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.GregorianCalendar to java.lang.Str
ing (through reference chain: io.springlets.data.web.select2.Select2DataWithConversion["results"])
2017-03-22 10:43:55.754  WARN - QP: - 6424 --- [io-8082-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionRes
olver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessa
geNotWritableException: Could not write content: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.ro
o.petclinic.domain.Pet] to type [java.lang.String] for value 'Pet {id='1', version='0', sendReminder
s='false', name='Mimi', weight='4.5', birthDay='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1490137200000,areFi
eldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",of
fset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[i
d=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMont
h=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,en
dDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=20
17,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_
IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFS
ET=0]', ITERABLE_TO_ADD_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!', IT
ERABLE_TO_REMOVE_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!'}org.spring
framework.roo.petclinic.domain.Pet@1f'; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.Spel
EvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from @javax.validation
.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Temporal @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeForm
at java.util.GregorianCalendar to java.lang.String (through reference chain: io.springlets.data.web.
select2.Select2DataWithConversion["results"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Js
onMappingException: Failed to convert from type [org.springframework.roo.petclinic.domain.Pet] to ty
pe [java.lang.String] for value 'Pet {id='1', version='0', sendReminders='false', name='Mimi', weigh
t='4.5', birthDay='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1490137200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=
true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=36000
00,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=360000
0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWee
k=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,
endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WE
EK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOU
R_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]', ITERABLE_TO_ADD_CANT_
BE_NULL_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!', ITERABLE_TO_REMOVE_CANT_BE_NULL
_MESSAGE='The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!'}org.springframework.roo.petclinic.domai
n.Pet@1f'; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:
(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.p
ersistence.Temporal @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.GregorianCalenda
r to java.lang.String (through reference chain: io.springlets.data.web.select2.Select2DataWithConver
sion["results"])
```

When i create a Visit the Pet don't show in List.

**date Date**

When i use an date Date field and create a Visit the Pet shown in List but the format is not correct.

**In Clinic Eaxmpel i have set a birthDay field to Pet and use it in entityFormatExpression**

```
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Pet --sequenceName PET_SEQ --entityFormatExpression "#{name} (#{type}) birthDay: #{birthDay}"

focus --class ~.domain.Pet
field date --fieldName birthDay --type java.util.Date --notNull --dateTimeFormatPattern "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

I have set dateTimeFormatPattern "dd.MM.yyyy"

In create edit/ view i see

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJOKB.jpg)

When i create a visit Object i see

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGr2R.jpg)

This is not the format i used for this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion to String when the JSON data is sent to the select2 component is performed by the [EntityExpression utilities](http://springlets.io/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/io/springlets/format/package-summary.html) which are registered in the *ConversionService*.

Those utilities use the SpEl support to parse the expression and convert the entity to a String. It seems the SpEl expression isn't using or doesn't have access to the ConversionService itself to convert to String the object properties included in the expression.

I've created an [issue in the Springlets project](https://github.com/DISID/springlets/issues/54) to take a look at the problem.

Comment: It has been solved in the Springlets project, so it will be available in the next Springlets release (1.2.0.RC2).

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I wait now for Spring Roo RC2